# Where do standard library assemblies come from for dependencies in .Net 6?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a .Net 6 application that uses Fluent NHibernate. Fluent NHibernate has several dependencies shown here:

[image]

The problem is that a security scan flags the use of System.Net.Http version 4.3.0.

Now I can't upgrade Fluent NHibernate any further, but from my research and understanding, when the application runs it will use whatever version of System.Net.Http is contained in the .Net 6 runtime installed on the machine (currently 6.0.9). This means it will use a version later than 4.3.0.

But to be honest I don't fully understand how this all works. Where does the dependency actually get loaded from? Does the runtime include the standard library? So then say it has System.Net.Http version 4.3.4. But the dependency is for 4.3.0, is version 4.3.0 somehow included in the Fluent NHibernate DLL so the unsecure version will be used?

If someone could help me understand how this works I would appreciate it. If you have links to documentation I can check out that would be great too.

Comment: this might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#cousin-dependencies

Comment: They are tiny little glue assemblies.  They don't contain any code (shaming your security software a bit), just [TypeForwardedTo] attributes for types in System.Net.Http.  Which tells the CLR that it needs to forward the type request to the actual implementing type, in your case located in C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.9\System.Net.Http.dll.  Maybe you ought to file a bug with your security software vendor, it's not doing a useful job.  If it is Fortify then an uninstall is certainly a good choice.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the comment, if you'd like to make it an answer I will accept it

Comment: I would like to add that after scanning the application with different security software the concerns about the mentioned assemblies were not raised. It appears that the scanning software is indeed failing at its job.